# What is the wave propagated away from an impulsively excited spherical shell?

Tags: mathematical-physics, waves

Consider a spherical shell of radius $R$ centered on the coordinate origin, and an impulsive excitation $\delta (t)$ distributed over its surface ('ie. a single layer'). Each point on the sphere’s surface becomes a point source, which radiates at the time zero a spherical wave given by $1/(4\pi r) \delta (t-r/c)$. $r$ is the radial distance from the point on the sphere to the point in space at which the resultant wave field $\phi$ will be considered at the time $t$. The propagation velocity is $c$. It is assumed that the sphere is transparent to radiation so that the *whole* sphere will contribute to the field at any given point in space.

Since the spherical source is symmetrical, at each point it suffices to compute the wave field along the radial line passing through the sphere center and the point. The wave field will be the same on any other radial line, so it can be considered as depending on only one spatial coordinate, and time, $\phi (z,t)$. The question is how to find $\phi (z,t)$.

[image: impulsively excited spherical shell]

At first sight it might seem that the impulse wave would be spherical, and centered on the origin of coordinates. However, the wave field at a point $z$ will get contributions from all the point sources lying on circular slices of the spherical shell beginning at the time $t = z/c$, see the figures, and will continue to contribute until $t = (z+2R)/c$. So it doesn't seem that one gets a 'cleanly propagating' impulsive spherical wave. The following shows how as time progresses (t0,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,...) corresponding circular slices of the impulsive spherical source contribute to the wave field at the stationary point z. So the field is stretched out in time.  Also note that with the foregoing approach the 'inward' propagating waves are included in the results at point z.

[image]

***If this problem has been addressed in published papers or in books I would really appreciate the references.***

Comment: You didn't tell **what** you distribute on the sphere? What radiates there, and which type of radiation?

Comment: @Sofia It doesn't really matter what kind of radiation it is. It could be any field as long as it satisfies the wave equation. I think he just wants to know the field's spatial profile as a function of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ro}{\mathbf{r}_o}
\newcommand{\zo}{z_o}
\newcommand{\rs}{\mathbf{r}_s}
\newcommand{\zs}{z_s}$My first answer was wrong, but I think it was wrong in an instructive way so I will leave it. Here is my second attempt. I couldn't find a clever way to do it, so I did it the straightforward way. I hope it is right this time, but there may be algebra mistakes.

If the sphere of radius $R$ is $S$, then we know that the field $f(\ro)$ at some observation point $\ro$ is given by 
$$ \int_S \frac{1}{4 \pi D} \delta (D - ct) d \rs, $$
where $D=D(\ro,\rs)=|\ro-\rs|$.

To evaluate the integral, we will choose coordinates. By symmetry we may choose $\ro = (0,0,\zo)$ with $\zo>0$. 
We may also choose $\rs = (\sqrt{R^2-\zs^2} \cos \phi,\sqrt{R^2-\zs^2}\sin \phi, \zs)$, so that $d \rs = R d \phi d \zs $, and $D^2=R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2$. Then the integral becomes 
$$ \int_S \frac{1}{4 \pi \sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} } \delta(\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} -ct) R d \phi d \zs $$

Doing the $\phi$ integral gives a factor of $2 \pi$, and we can pull the $2 \pi R$ out of the integral. We are left with

$$\frac{R}{2} \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} } \delta(\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} -ct) d \zs $$

Next we can work on the argument of the delta function. We want to find for what values of $\zs$ we have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
0&=\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} -ct \\
0&= R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2 -c^2t^2 \\
0&= R^2-\zs^2 + \zs^2-2\zs\zo+\zo^2 -c^2t^2 \\
 0&= R^2-2\zs\zo+\zo^2 -c^2t^2\\
  \zs &= \frac{R^2+\zo^2 -c^2t^2}{2\zo}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We also need to compute 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\qquad \partial_{\zs} \left(\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2} -ct\right) &= \frac{-z_s + (z_s-z_0)}{\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2}}\\
&=\frac{-z_0}{\sqrt{ R^2-\zs^2 + (\zo-\zs)^2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Then using $\delta(f(x)) = \delta(x)/|f'(x)|$, our integral becomes

$$ \frac{R}{2\zo} \int_{-R}^{R}  \delta\left(\zs-\frac{R^2+\zo^2 -c^2t^2}{2\zo}\right) d \zs $$

Now $\int_{-R}^{R}  \delta\left(\zs-\frac{R^2+\zo^2 -c^2t^2}{2\zo}\right) d \zs $ is either one or zero. We know from the way we picked the delta function that the integral is one when $|\zo-R|<ct<\zo+R$ and the integral is zero otherwise. Therefore $$f(z_o,t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{R}{2\zo}, & |\zo-R|<ct<\zo+R \\
0, & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I need a little time with this. I think your results are the same as mine that I produced with an utterly different approach--this may indicate that our results are correct. Thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Re.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209 .  This answer corroborates some of the computation for the sphere in the above paper using an altogether different approach.

Answer (score 1):

## Update: This solves the wave equation for the wrong initial conditions.

One way of seeing the solution is to see that a spherical wave emanating from a point is a solution, and if you take a picture of that wave at any time, you will see exactly your initial condition. This means one solution is an outgoing spherical wave. Also, since the wave equation has time reversal symmetry, an ingoing spherical wave must also be a solution. Therefore any superposition is also a solution. By conformally mapping the sphere to a plane and using symmetry, you can find that the correct superposition is when the ingoing and outgoing components have the same size in terms of integrated amplitude.

Comment: I should add that once the ingoing wave reaches the origin, it just becomes an outgoing wave.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question to more clearly explain the problem. It does not seem that separate converging and diverging impulsive spherical waves would be produced.  I think there may be a problem with mapping an infinite plane into a finite sphere in your approach.

Comment: You are right. See my other answer.

Comment: I was wrong.  Separate converging and diverging impulsive spherical waves are produced. See  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209 .

Comment: @user45664 It's been a while, but I think the thing is that the answer will depend not only on the initial amplitude, but also the initial time derivative. If you assume the initial time derivative is zero, I think you get the result from my other answer. If you choose the initial time derivative as appropriate for spherical ingoing or outing waves, you get those, or linear combinations if you choose a linear combination of the two initial conditions. But you definitely need to specify an initial condition for the time derivative of the field since the wave equation is second order.

Comment: I agree about the ICs.  Two would be required for a wave equation solution.  But this was for a geometric study of Huygens' Principle,  See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316994209 . The study was to see if HP could be derived via geometry alone without referring to the wave equation, or physics.