# Fundamental solutions and initial conditions (for d'Alembert operator)

Tags: causality, differential-equations, greens-functions, huygens-principle, plane-wave

I would like to understand the plane wave solution for the (3+1-dimensional) d'Alembert operator
$$
\square = \nabla^2 - \frac 1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\tag{1}
$$
in terms of its fundamental solutions. I know that the “function” (distribution)
$$
G(\vec x, \, t) = \frac{c}{4\pi r}\delta(ct - r),\tag{2}
$$
where $r = \lvert\vec x\rvert$, is a fundamental solution, that is, it satisfies
$$
\square G(\vec x, \, t) = -\delta^3(\vec x)\delta(t)\tag{3}.
$$
This fundamental solution can be seen as a mathematical statement of Huygens principle, since it states that the response to an instantaneous impulse at $t = 0$ and $\vec x = 0$ is a spherical propagation of that impulse with an attenuation given by the $1/r$ which ensures conservation of energy. So I wanted to see this principle in action in the simple example of a plane wave, but I'm having a hard time.

A plane wave $f(\vec x, \, t)$ propagating satisfies $\square f = 0$, but the fundamental solution method only allows me to find particular solutions of an inhomogeneous equation $\square f = g$, by convolution with the fundamental solution, i.e. $f = G \circledast g$. I figured that I could choose some singular $g$, i.e. $g \propto \delta(t)$, in order to have $g = 0$ most of the time. I thought that $g$ would then have the meaning of an “initial condition” or “initial impulse”. In particular, for a plane wave traveling in the $z$ direction, $g$ should also have translational symmetry with respect to $x$ and $y$, i.e. $$g(\vec x, \, t) = g(0, \, 0, \, z, \, t) \equiv g(z, \, t) = h(z)\delta(t).\tag{4}$$

But this doesn't seem to work since I'm not getting solutions of the form $g(ct - z)$.

*Question*: is this method correct in principle? i.e. is choosing a source proportional to $\delta(t)$ akin to choosing initial conditions? If not, is there a different way of doing that?

Comment: Green's function $G(\vec{x},t)$ helps you to get a solution $f$ of the *inhomogenous* wave equation $\square f=g$.
However, Green's function does not help you to get any solution of the *homogenous* wave equation $\square f=0$. You need other methods to achieve this.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch You are right, but what about $g(\vec x, \, t) = h(\vec x)\delta(t)$? It is not zero, but it is zero most of the time. I think that the solution shold then be something like $\theta(t)\phi(\vec x, \, t)$, where $\phi$ satisfies $\square\phi = 0$. Something like that, but not quite. Isn’t this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution $u(\vec{r},t)$ at a future spacetime point $(\vec{r},t)$ to the 2nd-order homogeneous [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) depends on Cauchy data (initial displacement & initial velocity) at the intersection between the past [light-cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_cone) and the [Cauchy surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_surface) $\{t=0\}$

$$\begin{align} u(\vec{r},t) ~=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \!d^3r^{\prime}~\partial_tG_{\rm ret}(\vec{r}\!-\!\vec{r}^{\prime},t) u(\vec{r}^{\prime},0)\cr
~+~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \!d^3r^{\prime}~G_{\rm ret}(\vec{r}\!-\!\vec{r}^{\prime},t) \partial_tu(\vec{r}^{\prime},0) \cr
~=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \!d^3r^{\prime}\frac{\delta^{\prime}(t-|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|)}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|}u(\vec{r}^{\prime},0)\cr
~+~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \!d^3r^{\prime}\frac{\delta(t-|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|)}{4\pi|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|} \partial_tu(\vec{r}^{\prime},0), \cr 
&\quad \text{for}\quad t~>~0, \tag{A}
\end{align}$$
cf. [Huygens' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle) and Ref. 1. Here$^1$
$$ G_{\rm ret}(\vec{r},t)~=~\frac{\theta(t)\delta(t^2-r^2)}{2\pi }~=~\frac{\delta(t-r)}{4\pi r}\tag{B}$$
is the retarded [Greens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function),

$$ \Box G_{\rm ret}(\vec{r},t)~=~-\delta^3(\vec{r})\delta(t).\tag{C} $$

References:

1. P.M. Morse & H. Feshbach, [*Methods of Theoretical Physics*](https://archive.org/details/morse_feshbach1/morse_feshbach1/page/845/mode/2up?view=theater), Vol. 1, 1953; section 7.3.

--

$^1$ In this answer we use the Minkowski signature $(-,+,+,+)$ and works in units where the wave speed is $c=1$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. 1. Also, I see from you solution that $\square u(\vec r,  \, t) = \partial_t\delta(t)u(\vec r, \, 0) + \delta(t)\partial_t u(\vec r, \, 0)$. Is this the point? 2. I was assuming that $\square u(\vec r, \, t) = u(\vec r, \, 0)\delta(t)$ and that was incorrect, right? I'm guessing that this depends on $\square$ being a second-order differential operator.

Comment: $\uparrow$ It seems you're getting the point.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: is this method correct in principle? i.e. is choosing a
> source proportional to δ(t) akin to choosing initial conditions? If
> not, is there a different way of doing that?

D'Alembert did more than deriving the wave equation, $\square$. He is credited with also supplying its solution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula .  Referring to this web page, the first two terms are due to the initial displacement at $t=0$.  The third term (the integral) is due to the initial velocity at $t=0$. So these are the initial conditions and their effects on the resulting wave.  My
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-99049-7 should help. Also I derive the third term geometrically in the notes in the supplementary information.  (There is some confusion as to whether this third term came from Euler)  Note that the third term is very important as it is the reason that the backward wave from the second term is canceled when the source speed is equal to the wave propagation speed.

Comment: I will take some time to read the article, which indeed seems helpful. Also, I found this question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160503/) that you asked quite some time ago. Do you think that the problem you had back then could be rephrased in terms of fundamental solutions of the d'Alembert operator?

Comment: From (physics.stackexchange.com/q/160503) " I agree about the ICs. Two would be required for a wave equation solution. But this was for a geometric study of Huygens' Principle, See researchgate.net/publication/316994209 . The study was to see if HP could be derived via geometry alone without referring to the wave equation, or physics."  So I was trying to get results geometrically with out using using wave equation solutions including fundamental solutions.